# FreeWall Selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm trying to add more than one id in the selector section of my Freewall code that I'm developing, but I got some errors and I'm not sure what the right way to do it. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.boxWrap', '.boxWrap2',
        animate: true,
        cellW: 330,
        cellH: 'auto',
        onResize: function() {
            wall.fitWidth(
            );
        }
    });
    wall.container.find('.boxWrap img').load(function() {
        wall.fitWidth();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector option doesn't support multiple string, you should use only one string like this:

```
selector:'.boxWrap, .boxWrap2' <-- single string
```

Summing it up:

```
    var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.boxWrap, .boxWrap2',
        animate: true,
        cellW: 330,
        cellH: 'auto',
        onResize:function(){
            wall.fitWidth();
        }
    });
    wall.container.find('.boxWrap img').load(function() {
        wall.fitWidth();
    });
```